# Google Maps center after resize

Tags: google-maps

I have a small issue when generating Google Maps.

I'm looking for a way of re-centering the map after a resize. My function allows the resize but I can't seen to figure out the center point.

```
function initialise() {
    var myMap = document.getElementById('map_div');
    google.maps.event.trigger(myMap, 'resize');       
};
```

Comment: What are you recentering on?  And how are you providing resizing?

Answer (score 0):

I think triggering **Google Map's `resize`** will not affect the position of the Google Maps.  However you can set/get the center position using the following methods

```
map.getCenter();
map.setCenter(position);
```

Here is your full code:

```
function initialise() {
    var myMap = document.getElementById('map_div');
    var centerPosition = myMap.getCenter();  //get the center position
    google.maps.event.trigger(myMap, 'resize');      
    myMap.setCenter(centerPosition);    // re-center the position
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[API v3.24 from May 23rd 2016](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) requires a different approach:

```
var myMap = null, myPlace = null;

function initialiseGmapsStuff(){
    myPlace = new google.maps.LatLng( 51.482496, 0.00 ); // Greenwich
    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 16, 
            center: myPlace,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, 
            scrollwheel: false, // Disable Mouse Scroll zooming (Essential for responsive sites!)
        };  
    myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmaps-container'), mapOptions);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'resize', $.throttle( 250, function(){ 
        if( myMap !== null && myPlace !== null ){
            myMap.setCenter( { lat: myPlace.lat(), lng: myPlace.lng() } );
        }
    } )
    );
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialiseGmapsStuff);
```

Notice my usage of [jQuery.throttle](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) - it is not required, but recommended. If you're not using jQuery you should obviously use some native form of throttling.